# Ubuntu 20.04 Upgrade Breaks NVidia GeForce GTX 1060

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, system-installation, nvidia-geforce

I upgraded my Linux desktop computer (ZaReason tower) to Ubuntu 20.04 a year ago and everything was working well.  I have an NVidia GeForce GTX 1060 video card, and the default Ubuntu drivers were working fine.

A normal software update about 6 months ago caused the video card to stop working.  I could only continue using the computer by manually booting into the older kernel, which was a pain.  I tried re-installing Ubuntu 20.04, but the installer crashes if you check this option:

- Install 3rd party device drivers for graphics and Wi-Fi hardware and additional media formats

[image: Don't click the "Install third-party..." option!]

So, ***do not check the box*** for "Install third-party software..." or the installer will crash.

Unfortunately, we need 3rd-party (i.e. NVidia) drivers for the GTX 1060 as the built-in `nouveau` drivers don't work!  How can we solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to manually install the correct NVidia drivers ***AFTER*** the normal installation gui completes.  When the installer asks you to reboot, ***don't do it!***.

When you see this dialog box:

[image]

don't click the "Restart Now" button!  Instead, **just click the "close" button** at the top right corner of the dialog box.  The desktop will close and restart in a few seconds.  At this point, you can right-click and open a terminal window.

At this point, we follow [the solution described here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux) under "Command Line Nvidia Installation Method" (2nd solution - the GNOME GUI method did not work for me).  We inquire about the drivers available for the installed devices. The command and result look like:

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C03sv00003842sd00006161bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]
driver   : nvidia-driver-450 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

We manually select the recommended driver and install it as follows:

```
$ sudo apt install -y nvidia-driver-460
```

Once this completes, the proper NVidia drivers have been installed. You can reboot the computer, remembering to remove the Ubuntu installation media when prompted.

Comment: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`does the same.